# Kubernetes authentication method to use for calling the K8 apis?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

i am quite new to kubernetes and I am looking towards certificate based authentication and token based authentication for calling K8 apis. To my understanding, I feel token based approach (openID + OAuth2) is better since id_token will get refreshed by refresh_token at a certain interval and it also works well with the login point(web browser) which is not the case with Certificate based approach . Any more thoughts to this ? I am working using minikube with kubernetes . Can anyone share their thoughts here ?

Answer (score 0):

Prefer  **OpenID Connect**  or  **X509 Client Certificate**-based authentication strategies over the others when authenticating users

- **X509 client certs**: decent authentication strategy, but you'd have to address renewing and redistributing client certs on a regular basis
- **Static Tokens**: avoid them due to their non-ephemeral nature
- **Bootstrap Tokens**: same as static tokens above
- **Basic Authentication**: avoid them due to credentials being transmitted over the network in cleartext
- **Service Account Tokens**: should not be used for end-users trying to interact with Kubernetes clusters, but they are the preferred authentication strategy for applications & workloads running on Kubernetes
- **OpenID Connect (OIDC) Tokens**: best authentication strategy for end users as OIDC integrates with your identity provider (e.g. AD, AWS IAM, GCP IAM ...etc)

I advice you to use OpenID Connect. OpenID Connect is based on OAuth 2.0. It is designed with more of an authentication focus in mind however. The explicit purpose of OIDC is to generate what is known as an id-token. The normal process of generating these tokens is much the same as it is in [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/).
OIDC brings a step closer to providing  with a user-friendly login experience and also to allow us to start restricting their access using RBAC.

Take also look on [Dex](https://github.com/coreos/dex)  which acts as a middleman in the authentication chain. It becomes the Identify Provider and issuer of ID tokens for Kubernetes but does not itself have any sense of identity. Instead, it allows you to configure an upstream Identity Provider to provide the users’ identity.

As well as any OIDC provider, Dex supports sourcing user information from GitHub, GitLab, SAML, LDAP and Microsoft. Its provider plugins greatly increase the potential for integrating with your existing user management system.

Another advantage that Dex brings is the ability to control the issuance of ID tokens, specifying the lifetime for example. It also makes it possible force your organization to re-authenticate. With Dex, you can easily revoke all tokens but there is no way to revoke a single token.

Dex also handles refresh tokens for users. When a user logs in to Dex they may be granted an id-token and a refresh token. Programs such as kubectl can use these refresh tokens to re-authenticate the user when the id-token expires. Since these tokens are issued by Dex, this allows you to stop a particular user refreshing by revoking their refresh token. This is really useful in the case of a lost laptop or phone.

Furthermore, by having a central authentication system such as Dex, you need only configure the upstream provider once.
An advantage of this setup is that if any user wants to add a new service to the SSO system, they only need to open a PR to  Dex configuration. This setup also provides users with a one-button “revoke access” in the upstream identity provider to revoke their access from all of our internal services. Again this comes in very useful in the event of a security breach or lost laptop.

More information you can find here: [kubernetes-single-sign-one-less-identity/](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-single-sign-one-less-identity/), [kubernetes-security-best-practices](https://dev.to/petermbenjamin/kubernetes-security-best-practices-hlk#conclusion).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this . I am planning to go with service-account token based approach and confused between whether to use certificates and service-account based approach ?

Comment: Please take a look: https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-security-rbac-tls/